# application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: not called after system terminates app

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, remote-notifications, background-mode

I have implemented `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`, which is necessary to run after receiving a push notification. I have also turned on "Background Fetch" and "Remote notifications" background modes. And my push notifications include the `content-available` flag, set to `1`.

If my app is in the Active, Background or Suspended state, this function gets called appropriately and the app temporarily moves into the Inactive state. However, if my app has been purged from the Suspended state due to a low memory issue (i.e. the user has opened a number of other apps since launching my app, a fairly common occurrence), it moves into the Not Running state. At that point, it doesn't call the `didReceiveRemoteNotifications` function.

[The documentation for this function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application) states:

> If you enabled the remote notifications background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a remote notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

The scenario where the user force quits the app and so the app doesn't call this function is acceptable. But what I'm seeing instead is if the *system* terminates the app for a fairly common reason, then this function doesn't get called.

I've also tried implementing `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`, the deprecated function, to see if that gets called when the app is in the Not Running state. It doesn't.